# Does Heroku provide any VPN client like AWS Client VPN?

Tags: heroku, vpn

I want to host a database in Heroku server and also a django application. The problem is: To transfer data to my Heroku database i would need be connected to a VPN. Does Heroku provides a way to connect to a VPN in order to access another database, like AWS client VPN?

My infra would be like this:

Airflow running DAGs to pull data from a AWS database that requires VPN connection to source from it. I would transfer the data from this AWS database to my heroku database.

Is it possible?

Thank you

Another thing that i'm wondering is if it is possible to connect Heroku to AWS client VPN, in case Heroku does not have something similar or a way to do this step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Heroku does provides a VPN labelled as Heroku Private Spaces and Shield Spaces.

Here is the link
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-vpn-connection